# Web App packages structure for a big web project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, package

I am creating an application using servlets and JSP. I would like to know how to arrange modules as packages in the application. I.e.: I want my servlets in `testproject.web`, models in `testproject.models` and `testproject.dataaccess` and so on.

Can I create different packages and arrange my source code inside the relevant packages?

I would like to know the best practices to do this. I assume that all the source code could create in a single dynamic web project in Eclipse.

I am basically a .NET programmer, there we can create different projects inside a single solution.

Comment: Java has a `package` concept, yes. Is that all you are asking about?

Comment: yes. I would like to get additional suggestions if any

Answer (score 3):

You can use `package` declarations, sure, though you could also use Maven / Gradle to create multi-module project. Those also act as your dependency management tools like NuGet in .NET.

An example `pom.xml` section from a Java web project I have.

Dependencies are setup from bottom-up from most depends to least. (That's setup by the other `pom.xml` files)

```
  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>service-templating-core</module>
    <module>service-templating-velocity</module>
    <module>service-rest-jersey</module>
    <module>service-rest-sparkjava</module>
    <module>web</module>
  </modules>
```

Where the modules are

- `core`: Base Java objects with little dependencies
- `web`: The "entry-point" to the site and holds static resources
- `service-rest-*`: Handles REST API routes (implemented JAX-RS or SparkJava)
- `service-templating-*`: Handles HTML templating (implemented Velocity templates)
- `service-templating-core`: Handles binding Java objects to an abstract `ViewTemplate` class

In Eclipse, these "look" like separate projects, but really it's just one Maven project.

[image: eclipse projects]

---

You can still have packages in each of those projects. It's all still Java

---

I'm not using that in production, it was mostly to quickly switch between frameworks to learn them.
You could easily add in a `db-mysql` or `db-mongo` modules to that, if needed, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Java has `package` concept you can arrange your code in different packages
such as
create different packages and arrange source code inside the relevant packages

> sample example

```
 ui
 presentation
 business
 dataacess
 utils
 library
```

you can create different `packages` based on your architecture and or based on the layers or tiers in your application.

**Note :-** The above one is just sample you can arrange package based on your application implementation.

Comment: Why negative need to explain, it will be helpful

Comment: Ok. I hope there is no issue to do it like testproject.ui, testproject.business etc...